# Filter each dataframe in a list by a column value in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of 18 dataframes all looking something akin to this:

```
 Gene ID    HMMER   Hotpep  DIAMOND #ofTools
actino_5_2__00070   GT20(2-473) GT20(5) GT20    3
actino_5_2__00270   CE1(65-331) -   -   1
actino_5_2__00610   GT4(224-382)    GT4(7)  GT4 3
actino_5_2__00950   GH3(26-242) GH3(2)  GH3 3
actino_5_2__01300   GH23(67-175)    -   -   1
actino_5_2__01490   GT4(381-524)    GT4(82) GT4 3
actino_5_2__01990   CE1(114-349)    -   -   1
```

I want to filter each dataframe in the list but the value of the last column being >= 2. So pretty much this `filt_comb_data = comb_data[comb_data$X >= 2,]` but for a list. I started by using lapply with the following:

```
filt_datalist = lapply(datalist, function(x){
  x[x[5],] >= 2
})
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
filt_datalist = lapply(datalist, function(x){
    x[x[, 5] >= 2,]
})
```

This should be it. You take the dataframe (`x`) and filter everything where the 5th column (`x[, 5]`) is `>= 2`.

Comment: Btw: I would try to avoid `x[, 5]` - if you know the column name `x$columnName` is better, because the column of interest might also be at another location.